# send embeds from a cog discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

after searching for a while, i can't find anything that fixes this, so i thought i'd ask around to see if anyone can fix this:

i'm building a discord bot in discord.py, and i can get the cogs to send normal messages (when i run ,help it responds with plain text), but i'd like to get it to send an embed. here's my code currently:

```
from discord.ext import commands

class helpCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    
    @commands.command()
    async def help(self,ctx):
        self.embed = discord.Embed(title="example title", description="example description", color=0x43b128)
        await ctx.send(embed=self.embed)

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(helpCog(bot))
```

i know it's probably something obvious, but if someone could point it out, it'd be much appreciated

whenever i run this code, if i put `print('test')` just before the `await ctx.send(embed=self.embed)` line, that prints out, but nothing after the line does. no error messages are printed to the console.

thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have to do anything special to get embeds to send from cogs. Did you configure logging? If it doesn't send then you should get an error, but if logging isn't set up then you won't see it. _Also why are you storing it in an attribute instead of just a variable?_

Comment: PS this isn't how you should be creating help commands, see https://gist.github.com/InterStella0/b78488fb28cadf279dfd3164b9f0cf96

Comment: @stijndcl honestly i'm not sure why i didn't just use a variable, i checked a few places online and was pretty much trying anything in the hope it'd work. i just tried setting up logging, and i'm not sure if i did it correctly or not, but there seems to be nothing there yet, i'll keep poking around to see if i can find something. i will also have a look at your second comment once i've got this working, as this is currently my priority

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was being stupid: it was a permissions issue in the channel I was using to test the bot on Discord. The code I posted above works (i think? i don't think i changed anything)

anyway the point is there was nothing that needed to be fixed with the code, i was just being really stupid.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).